# I wonder how native English speaker perceives 'make' in this expression

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, expressions

**"make landfall"**

e.g, The hurricane made landfall.

I know what "landfall" means.

I know "make landfall" means "*to reach or hit or strike a certain area*."
But I can't understand well the meaning of "make" in the expression, as I am not a native English speaker.

I wonder how native English speaker perceives it.

Please don't give the answer that "It's just idiom."

Comment: 'Made' can be interpreted to mean 'achieved'.

Comment: ... or "accomplished".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not a native speaker, but the way I understand this phrase is through the way of analogy. I think the meaning of "make", as in "make landfall", is close to its meaning in "I've made it." or "He makes a really good teacher." It denotes the achievement of a certain result. Hope that helps.

Comment: +1.  There is also the following usage of “make”: “This train will **make** the border by sunrise.”  (This seems to be a variant of “**make it to** + a place.” [(ARRIVE or REACH)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/make)